# CSS page with specific name not loading in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

When displaying my webpage XMLSummary.html, Firefox v24.4.0 will hang and refuses to load the css file XMLSummary.css. The css file name does not appear in the network debugging console. Chrome v36 and Internet Explorer v8 will load the css file correctly. If I copy the contents of XMLSummary.css to test.css and change the link's target to test.css, the page loads properly.

```
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/XMLSummary.css"/>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/test.css"/>
```

Why does Firefox prevent a CSS file from loading when it has a certain name? Is there a way to keep my original file name, or do I have to rename it?

At first I thought firefox was blocking css files that have the same name as the html file that loads them, but I also have a file named DNSSummary.html that loads its DNSSummary.css file normally in Firefox.

A similar question has been asked before, but was closed without being answered: [firefox-does-not-load-css-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464879/firefox-does-not-load-css-files). I have already tried clearing my cache and stating charset UTF-8 in both the html file and the css file. I just installed firefox and do not have AdBlock.

Comment: After you copied the text of XMLSummary.css to the other file, were the files identical? Could you check with a hex editor or something? And/or if you simply _rename_ the CSS file to something else, rather than copying, does it work?

Comment: I tried renaming the css file with linux's mv. It worked when renamed to XMLSummar.html and changed the html link to remove the y, but stopped loading when renamed back to XMLSummary.html and changed the link back.

Comment: Hm. I don't know what to say now. You did mean `.css`, right? Otherwise I may be confused.

Comment: Oh. Yeah. That's a typo. I did mean .css

Comment: Sorry then, but I don't have a solution. I can't duplicate it here and I can't suggest disabling add-ons, since you don't have any.